# jQuery Mobile + Phonegap Icons Moved

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, cordova, icons

I am using jQuery Mobile + Phonegap, when I run the app on chrome all the buttons (lists, back, home) of jQuery work perfect.
When I put it on my Android device all the button icons seem to be moved like the css is wrong so they are either grambled (like half another icon is show instead) or they do not appear at all and the space is left blank.

Any suggestions?
I am using jQuery Mobile 1.0.1.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried loading the JQM site with the android browser, outside of phone gap? This will help isolate the problem to be phone-gap specific or a code implementation issue.  Also, if you resize your chrome window to be small, do you see the problems there?

Comment: It also has the same behaviour on Mobile Browser...

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to link to the site or include the markup (even a sample markup that duplicates the problem will work)?

Comment: Solved by redownloading everything! really strange...
Thank you very much for your help!